# How to disable dialog that shows on pasting code in NetBeans?

Tags: html, netbeans

When I paste a piece of code in the current HTML file NetBeans (12.5) always shows me the following dialog:

[image]

So, I need to press Esc every time. How to disable this dialog not to show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying the *Completion Window* for HTML files is enabled by default, but it is easy to disable it:

- Select **Tools > Options > Editor**
- Select **HTML** from the **Language** droplist
- Uncheck the **Auto Popup Completion Window**  checkbox
- Click **Apply**

[image: DisableDialog]

Notes:

- The change is immediately effective.
- There are several other checkboxes in that same **Options** dialog (as shown above) which allow the *Completion Window* to still popup in specific situations.
- Similar functionality for the *Completion Window* is also provided for some other languages, such as Java, JavaScript and PHP. Just select other languages from the **Language** drop list to see what functionality is available.